# Version issue with embedding bokeh on heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh

I am having a problem embedding Bokeh on Heroku. It works fine on my local machine, but something is wrong, when I try on heroku. Below is the html file. My guess is the data is not embedding correctly. For instance `__ndarray__` has some weird characters instead of the data. I had been struggling to find a solution. Can someone provide help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Time-series plot</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.3.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.3.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
  var fn = function() {
    Bokeh.safely(function() {
      var docs_json = {"25435e2e-0cb3-47b8-8bf1-32c906b6f420":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"10baebf3-faeb-46d1-859d-3263c6cd9354","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"2be1d120-5724-460f-b0f0-7231d7e46726","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"base":60,"mantissas":[1,2,5,10,15,20,30],"max_interval":1800000.0,"min_interval":1000.0,"num_minor_ticks":0},"id":"062863cd-1ed4-4b1a-af68-b016860bd87a","type":"AdaptiveTicker"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"616ed4ac-d4c5-4010-beff-1589b8b73f52","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"max_interval":500.0,"num_minor_ticks":0},"id":"9517227c-f613-42bc-a35e-ae3c9543f317","type":"AdaptiveTicker"},{"attributes":{"items":[{"id":"2fd93036-1ef3-4d56-bad7-88fdf9352c21","type":"LegendItem"}],"location":"top_left","plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"13ee15d7-a5bd-40c8-b896-6d8955b883ee","type":"Legend"},{"attributes":{},"id":"751d139b-ceca-4eec-acbd-41e25b434a73","type":"DatetimeTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"34d4f26b-a640-4129-88fd-578633815bbd","type":"YearsTicker"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"f8b00322-303d-4c46-a577-b48573240aa7","type":"DatetimeAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"77143d5d-525f-4d25-acea-5c424eded496","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_height":500,"plot_width":800,"renderers":[{"id":"f8b00322-303d-4c46-a577-b48573240aa7","type":"DatetimeAxis"},{"id":"aa08aef8-adbe-4ac9-bb30-3276e6833765","type":"Grid"},{"id":"77143d5d-525f-4d25-acea-5c424eded496","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"bff245c2-03a5-411c-a938-515909623506","type":"Grid"},{"id":"616ed4ac-d4c5-4010-beff-1589b8b73f52","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"4311d6d9-1db1-4a28-b427-4f0d3da33a8d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"13ee15d7-a5bd-40c8-b896-6d8955b883ee","type":"Legend"},{"id":"baee81d6-e664-46ba-b9d3-2e030d7fd672","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"ed0051be-e237-4b47-8663-afb3b1f1ce7c","type":"Title"},"tool_events":{"id":"93f77166-b47d-4147-8f40-60587534bb6e","type":"ToolEvents"},"toolbar":{"id":"9af07266-a889-4c6c-8e88-7a1f31d740f0","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"10baebf3-faeb-46d1-859d-3263c6cd9354","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_range":{"id":"4ffcdd86-22b4-4b7a-be07-ac70c84c27db","type":"DataRange1d"}},"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"band_fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"band_fill_color":{"value":"olive"},"dimension":1,"grid_line_alpha":{"value":0},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"06fb8ff2-d611-405b-be38-e171cbf46d8c","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"bff245c2-03a5-411c-a938-515909623506","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"months":[0,2,4,6,8,10]},"id":"5fc979d4-46a9-469c-af56-527c9d4cb163","type":"MonthsTicker"},{"attributes":{"num_minor_ticks":5},"id":"f897d924-3e38-464c-a5af-8eb5d3b68094","type":"DatetimeTicker"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"6d6fc44a-63fb-4b3d-95b8-3d219a92f1ca","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"dfd7789a-7064-469a-aed1-0f49e3bb6fb7","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"2be1d120-5724-460f-b0f0-7231d7e46726","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"baee81d6-e664-46ba-b9d3-2e030d7fd672","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"06fb8ff2-d611-405b-be38-e171cbf46d8c","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"days":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]},"id":"413be9a6-f974-4bb0-a547-fd109820f4ac","type":"DaysTicker"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"ad71abf4-7812-47df-974c-bdf963267996","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"4651a289-09bc-4249-ab43-dcf8d0073edf","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"a630d9b3-35fa-4631-8971-6ffe63f5f285","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"2d21e9c6-d52c-4788-a4c1-96bb295c2421","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"94e83390-ed62-4543-81c3-177bb7404bd0","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"7d10de35-f889-4af5-a737-7b7e18177842","type":"BoxSelectTool"}]},"id":"9af07266-a889-4c6c-8e88-7a1f31d740f0","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"4ffcdd86-22b4-4b7a-be07-ac70c84c27db","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"days":[1,8,15,22]},"id":"f1182eaa-c07f-4f7a-b6e2-e2e003b26503","type":"DaysTicker"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":"Data for GOOG from Quandle WIKI set"},"id":"ed0051be-e237-4b47-8663-afb3b1f1ce7c","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"base":24,"mantissas":[1,2,4,6,8,12],"max_interval":43200000.0,"min_interval":3600000.0,"num_minor_ticks":0},"id":"2cee3978-4144-4aee-9971-b93db0a60f31","type":"AdaptiveTicker"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"94e83390-ed62-4543-81c3-177bb7404bd0","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"2d21e9c6-d52c-4788-a4c1-96bb295c2421","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"column_names":["x","y"],"data":{"x":{"__ndarray__":"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","dtype":"float64","shape":[711]},"y":{"__ndarray__":"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","dtype":"float64","shape":[711]}}},"id":"6d6fc44a-63fb-4b3d-95b8-3d219a92f1ca","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"93f77166-b47d-4147-8f40-60587534bb6e","type":"ToolEvents"},{"attributes":{"line_color":{"value":"blue"},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"dfd7789a-7064-469a-aed1-0f49e3bb6fb7","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"grid_line_alpha":{"value":0},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"f897d924-3e38-464c-a5af-8eb5d3b68094","type":"DatetimeTicker"}},"id":"aa08aef8-adbe-4ac9-bb30-3276e6833765","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"label":{"value":"Adj. Close"},"renderers":[{"id":"baee81d6-e664-46ba-b9d3-2e030d7fd672","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"2fd93036-1ef3-4d56-bad7-88fdf9352c21","type":"LegendItem"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"ad71abf4-7812-47df-974c-bdf963267996","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"48053516-3d87-4026-986f-48129fc60e01","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"months":[0,6]},"id":"36d97b27-7fc5-4095-a5b7-6ec9003c8381","type":"MonthsTicker"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Date","formatter":{"id":"751d139b-ceca-4eec-acbd-41e25b434a73","type":"DatetimeTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"f897d924-3e38-464c-a5af-8eb5d3b68094","type":"DatetimeTicker"}},"id":"f8b00322-303d-4c46-a577-b48573240aa7","type":"DatetimeAxis"},{"attributes":{"days":[1,15]},"id":"5c4984ed-252e-4eae-a6a2-1cf39a55814a","type":"DaysTicker"},{"attributes":{"months":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]},"id":"4d867e4d-d57d-47b0-a9ed-037e2feeb430","type":"MonthsTicker"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"4311d6d9-1db1-4a28-b427-4f0d3da33a8d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"overlay":{"id":"4311d6d9-1db1-4a28-b427-4f0d3da33a8d","type":"BoxAnnotation"},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"renderers":[{"id":"baee81d6-e664-46ba-b9d3-2e030d7fd672","type":"GlyphRenderer"}]},"id":"7d10de35-f889-4af5-a737-7b7e18177842","type":"BoxSelectTool"},{"attributes":{"days":[1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28]},"id":"18e0bad7-fd4d-483a-a66d-8326fd4cb8d4","type":"DaysTicker"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Price","formatter":{"id":"48053516-3d87-4026-986f-48129fc60e01","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"06fb8ff2-d611-405b-be38-e171cbf46d8c","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"77143d5d-525f-4d25-acea-5c424eded496","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"months":[0,4,8]},"id":"541618b2-937c-4225-a9e3-c94d0e9cac89","type":"MonthsTicker"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"4651a289-09bc-4249-ab43-dcf8d0073edf","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"616ed4ac-d4c5-4010-beff-1589b8b73f52","type":"BoxAnnotation"},"plot":{"id":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}},"id":"a630d9b3-35fa-4631-8971-6ffe63f5f285","type":"BoxZoomTool"}],"root_ids":["8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.12.4"}};
      var render_items = [{"docid":"25435e2e-0cb3-47b8-8bf1-32c906b6f420","elementid":"f91b2880-937e-436d-88b0-04c339475f6f","modelid":"8fa14872-25cd-4dec-82ab-b1dd9b8a852f"}];

      Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
    });
  };
  if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
})();

</script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class=page>
    <h1> Generated plot for GOOG </h1>
    <h4> <a href="/index">Back</a></h4>

<div class="bk-root">
    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="f91b2880-937e-436d-88b0-04c339475f6f"></div>
</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are `numpy` versions on the local machine and on Heroku the same?

Comment: The `__ndarray__` is a binary encoding of the data (added in `Bokeh 0.12.4`) that is far more efficient in almost all cases, and *especially* much better for images. The "weird characters" are entirely expected and normal. Are there any warning or error message in your browser's JavaScript console when you try to load the page from Heroku?

Comment: Thanks for the comments ! I found the problem to be the versioning of `bokeh`. In the html file I had `0.12.3`, but my `requirements.txt` had `bokeh>=0.12.3`, and because of which heroku was using `0.12.4`. Now I changed my `requirements.txt` to `bokeh==0.12.3` and it works perfect now ! Thanks for the insights, I would have not figured it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

Problem to be the versioning of `bokeh`. In the html file  had `0.12.3`, but my `requirements.txt` had `bokeh>=0.12.3`, and because of which heroku was using `0.12.4`. Changing the `requirements.txt` file to `bokeh==0.12.3` fixed the problem.

Comment: had a similar problem and this worked for me.  thanks!